# Connecting to the same IP address and port many times from the same PC

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient

I am testing a device and one of the items to test is they say I can have as many connections to it as I like. Obviously there is a limit but what is it. I thought I would put a simple app together to just make connections to the device.

I find in c# it is easy to make a connection so my theory is just give each connection a unique name e.g. tcpclnt_1, tcpclnt_2, tcpclnt_3 etc.

I started with just one connection and that works well. My problem is that I can hard code each name  so I can declare

```
public TcpClient tcpclnt_1 = new TcpClient();
public TcpClient tcpclnt_2 = new TcpClient();
```

but this is not dynamic. Below is some code where I outline what I was trying to do. It will not work as I cannot find a way to dynamically change each tcpclnt_x to a unique name. I may not even be doing this the correct way so any ideas on how I can connect multiple times to the same device?

```
 public TcpClient tcpclnt_x = new TcpClient();
 int iterations = Decimal.ToInt32(numupdown_iterations.Value);

        private void btn_creatConnections_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            {
                tcpclnt_x.Connect("192.168.127.254", 721);
            }

        }

        private void btn_delete_connections_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            {
                tcpclnt_x.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Keep 'em in a list? Or a dictionary? Note that each open connection should have a unique local address/port combination which can be used to identify them.

Comment: You cannot have multiple connections using the same connect address and same port number.  If you open multiple connections you are going to have to change the port and/or the IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to investigate lists and other collections.

```
public List<TcpClient> tcpclnts = new List<TcpClient>();
int iterations = Decimal.ToInt32(numupdown_iterations.Value);

    private void btn_creatConnections_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            var client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect("192.168.127.254", 721);
            tcpclnts.Add(client);
        }

    }

    private void btn_delete_connections_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            tcpclnts[x].Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank-you that has solved it and I have learned a new area of c# regarding lists. I now have many connections to the same IP add and port.